# How to calculate the RMS of an AC PWM?

Tags: ac, pwm, modulation, rms

I am looking at a servo, which is driven by PWM.
The PWM signal itself modulates NOT DC but a sine AC, so when Throttle is set to 100%, I can see a rather nicely drawn sine wave. But when Throttle is set to values below, the sine becomes edgy, with gaps, just like PWM is supposed to do.

Now I'd like to calculate the RMS voltage. Logically, with full Throttle, RMS voltage fits (1/sqrt(2)) * Vmax quite well. Though for lower settings, a formula is needed.

I know the PWM's Frequency, duty cycles, Vmax.
Any idea?

Comment: Is it a true sinewave (range -1 to 1) or a unipolar raised sine (range 0 to 1)?

Comment: Actually, it is a true sinewave (amplitude: -/+ 12V)

Comment: Then Spehro's answer applies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The generic formula is:

$$V_{RMS}=\frac{1}{T}\sqrt{\int_{t=0}^{t=T} (V(t))^2 dt}$$

and for a sinus-shaped voltage:

$$V_{RMS}=\frac{1}{T}\sqrt{\int_{t=0}^{t=T} (V_0\sin(\omega t))^2 dt}=\frac{V_0}{T}\sqrt{\int_{t=0}^{t=T} (\sin(\omega t))^2 dt}=...=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}V_0$$

Now, it depends on how the PWM signal looks like. Let's say it just cuts away a part beginning at each zero crossing of the sine, then you get:

$$V_{RMS}=\frac{2}{T}\sqrt{\int_{t=p\cdot T/2 }^{t=T/2} (V_0\sin(\omega t))^2 dt}=...$$

(note: I have reduced the calculation to a halve wave, p is the fraction cut out by the PWM)

A more complex pattern would need to split the integral into all those intervals where the PWM is not zero. May be, your scope can calculate the RMS voltage numerically?

If the PWM frequency is very high compared to the sinus frequency (let's say 100 times higher), you just get 
$$V_{RMSPWM}=p\cdot V_{Rms}$$

because the PWM acts in time intervals where the sinus is almost constant.

If the PWM period does not equal the sinus period, you can get something similar to a beat. But on average, the PWM gives the fraction of periods for which you have the sinus voltage or zero for a given angle. This also leads to a factor p.

Answer (score 1):

If the PWM is random (not phase control) then you should average \$\sigma\$ Vrms, where \$\sigma\$ is the PWM duty cycle (0~1) and Vrms is the RMS voltage at 100% PWM.

The reason is that you'll get average voltage of Vrms when the PWM is 'on' and 0 when the PWM is 'off'.  In other words, it's the same as PWM'ing a DC voltage.

If it's phase control rather than random PWM, you have to do the integration to find the RMS voltage as a function of trigger angle. I believe you find it to be

Vout = Vrms\$\times\$((1/\$\pi\$)  (\$\phi\$ - sin(\$\phi\$) cos(\$\phi\$)))

for trigger angle \$\phi\$
0\$\le\phi\$\$\le\ \pi\$

Comment: So far, my idea was to put the sine function into the RMS formula. Finally, I would have to integrate over the square of the sine function.